# Cordova file transfer plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i am creating ionic app where i want to download a image which is dynamic and using cordova file transfer plugin  but its not working kindly check where i did the mistake .

> Error :- url is not defined ,Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

```
  $

scope.downloadImage = function() {
            $http.get('http://sabkideal.com/phpapi_/cashback.php').success(function(response) {
      $scope.data = response;

       for (var i=0 ;i <response.length; i++)
       {
        var url = response[i].image;
        var deal = response[i].id;
        //url showing the same url every time i click and not jumping to next statement when click on send image download .
       console.log(deal);

      console.log(url);

      var filename = url.split("/").pop  ;

 console.log(filename);

      var     targetPath = encodeURI(cordova.file.dataDirectory + fileName);
       console.log(targetPath);

    var   options = {};
       var  trustHosts = true;

        }


                $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
      .then(
        function(result) {
          alert('Download success');
          refreshMedia.refresh(targetPath);
        },
        function(err) {
          alert('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        },
        function(progress) {
          // progressing download...
        })

});


     }
```

Comment: Did you check what `response.image` returns ?

Comment: its return nothing .. undefined

Comment: Then maybe you are not parsing the response correctly. alert or log the response and traverse to image path correctly

Comment: kindly give some suggestion how to do it

Comment: Try `response[0].image` you will get the image url for first element

Comment: check now its gives me image link but some how dont download the image

Comment: and give the same image

Comment: yes because you have to loop the response to get all the image and use `$cordovaFileTransfer.download` function to download the image

Comment: kindly tell how to make it bit confused

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the data return is not undefined. By implement the checking you can check whether the data is undefined or not. Use then instead of success because it is deprecated in Angular 1.5 and below

```
 $http.get('http://sabkideal.com/phpapi_/cashback.php').then(function(response) {
      $scope.data = response.data;

       // Need to check response data so that it is not undefined
       if ($scope.data !== undefined && $scope.data !== null && $scope.data !=="") {
         for (var i=0 ;i <$scope.data.length; i++)
         {
              // Checking also need to be done here
             if ($scope.data[i].image !== undefined && $scope.data[i].image 
                                        !==null && $scope.data[i].image !== "")  {
                 var url = $scope.data[i].image;                    
                 var filename = url.split("/").pop  ;
             }
```

Comment: still getting the error FileTransfer is not defined

Comment: The error you state in your question is not related to File Transfer.  Make sure you've install properly the plugin -  cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer , and use the injected $cordovaFileTransfer in the controller instead of new FileTransfer like that. Thanks

Comment: still the image in not download form  the server

Comment: .controller('imageCtrl',function($scope, $http,$window,$cordovaFileTransfer) {